# Как сделать авто-выход из программы после завершения последнего действия на C++?

Tags: c++

Как сделать авто-выход из программы после завершения последнего действия на C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После завершения **последнего** действия, выход из программы произойдет сам собой. Например:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    cout << "Hello, World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Последнее действие - возврат комадной return. После этого происходит **автовыход**. Если же имелось в виду, какое-то **произвольное** действие, то можно выйти с помощью функции exit из stdlib

```
# include <stdlib.h>

// ... последнее действие
exit(0);
```

Также можно выйти, выбросив необрабатываемое исключение, что приведет к аварийному останову.

```
throw;
```

Comment: В случае приложений с GUI возможно придется использовать другие вызовы. Например, <a href=http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#quit>QCoreApplication::Quit</a> для тулкита Qt. Возможна посылка сообщения WM_QUIT или SIGTERM. Или что-то подобное.

Answer (score 0):

Из `int main()`? `return 0`. По сути она и так выйдет после последнего действия. 
"Учите матчасть"